# Relocate postgresql.conf file

Tags: postgresql

I need change postgresql.conf file location of PostgreSQL 14 on Ubuntu.

I can change the hba_file and other files location from inside of postgresql.conf file, but I don't know how to change the config_file location and start postgres.

Can you help me on it?

Comment: PostgreSQL configuration files are stored in the /etc/postgresql/<version>/main directory. You could use a symlink if you want to place them somewhere else and for starting just check via `systemctl status postgresql` if its running - if not start it via `systemctl start postgresql`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  The best way to do it depends on why.

Comment: I have a one system which needs postgresql.conf to be in PGDATA as redhat. But on ubuntu it placed under /etc. There have not any way to relocate it?